# FabricJS: Load multiple fontFamilies at the same time?

Tags: font-face, fabricjs

I'm working on an editor based on the awesome [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/)

I don't have any problems setting a text elements fontFamily when there is only a single font: `text.fontFamily='Helvetica';`

The problem is when I try to use the amazing [Hoefler & **Jones**](https://www.typography.com) typography.com service at the same time.

The issue is they essentially use dataURL's to serve the files which is fine for most HTML because in the CSS you do: `font-family: "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B";`

What happens is 50% of the letterforms are loaded into the "A" or "B" item (totally at random it seems) so AaCcEeRrNn... is from "A" and BbDdFfMmXx... is from "B"

In HTML if the characters aren't in the "A" file it "defaults" to the "B" file.

I can't figure out how to get this to work in Fabric... Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this work in normal canvas? can you write a canvas text, without fabric, with this font?

Comment: That's an interesting question, admittedly I haven't tried it yet, I'll try to do it with a vanilla canvas and get back to you